# java regex for a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to generate a regex for a string like "S67-90". 
I used a syntax "String pattern = "\w\d\d\W\d\d"", but I would like to specify that the first word character should always start wit "S". Can anybody please help me with this?

My sample code is :

```
                      String pattern = "\\w\\d\\d\\W\\d\\d";
                      Pattern p = Pattern.compile((pattern));
                      Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
                      if (m.find()) {
                      System.out.println("Yes!It is!");
                       }
                     else{
                     System.out.println("No!Its not  :(");
                         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your match to start with the letter `S`, you can do as above. However, if you want to specify that the string must start with an `S`, you must do this: `^S\\d\\d\\W\\d\\d`. This will instruct the regex engine to start matching from the beginning. This regex: `S\\d\\d\\W\\d\\d` will match `bla bla S67-90`. This regex: `^S\\d\\d\\W\\d\\d` will match only strings starting with `S`, so it will match only `S67-90`.

Comment: Superrr..!! This works as well. I was looking for this exactly! Thanks!

Comment: @dmurali: You could also refactor your regex to something like this: `^S\\d{2}\\W\\d{2}`. This should do the same work as the one you proposed, just less verbose. If this answer answered your query, then just mark it so :)

Answer (score 5):

Just replace first `\\w` with `S` in your pattern.

```
  String pattern = "S\\d\\d\\W\\d\\d";
```

Comment: Awww..! Thank you..! I already tried this one but was not sure if I was right.

Answer (score 3):

Easy, put an "S": `String pattern = "[S]\\d\\d\\W\\d\\d";`

Answer (score 0):

Simply change first \w to S

```
S\d\d\W\d\d
```